# Is there an iPhone app for outlining that has a decent web/desktop companion?

Tags: iphone, applications

I am looking for an *outliner app for iPhone*, with either a desktop or web counterpart.

Comment: You can ask your meta question on http://meta.gadgets.stackexchange.com, but personally I would leave the tags as they are and elaborate on the question. What do you mean by outliner app? What features are you looking for? etc.

Comment: I mean something that has all the normal outliner features, with demotion and promotion of headings and subheadings, etc.
The only other requirement I can think of is that it has a web/desktop client that syncs with the iPhone app. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Evernote should work for you, there are web/desktop (PC/Mac) and iPad apps, as well as the iPhone app.

Comment: From what I have read, Evernote is not suited at all to outlining. Quoting from a user: 'Outline better. For the love of dog, why can't I tab, shift-tab for indenting just like nearly every other outlining program out there?'

Comment: Yeah Evernote isn't quite what I had in mind either.  Something a little more along the lines of Freemind/FreePlane or the old Bonzi for Palm OS.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app call Outliner for iPad and iPhone, which has an web companion.  It works for now, but I am waiting for OminiOutliner to come out in 2011 (for iPad, not for iPhone), which should be a much better solution.